# Installing mesa Vulkan driver on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, 17.10, vulkan

I'm trying to install Vulkan on Ubuntu 17.10.

So far I've tried:

```
sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers vulkan-utils
```

This does not appear to work, since I get the following output from `vulkaninfo`:

```
===========
VULKAN INFO
===========

Vulkan API Version: 1.0.42

INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/<redacted>/.local/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/steamoverlay_i386.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /home/<redacted>/.local/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/steamoverlay_x86_64.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found ICD manifest file /etc/vulkan/icd.d/intel_icd.i686.json, version "1.0.0"
ERROR: [loader] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found ICD manifest file /etc/vulkan/icd.d/radeon_icd.x86_64.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found ICD manifest file /etc/vulkan/icd.d/intel_icd.x86_64.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found ICD manifest file /etc/vulkan/icd.d/radeon_icd.i686.json, version "1.0.0"
ERROR: [loader] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found ICD manifest file /usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/radeon_icd.x86_64.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found ICD manifest file /usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/intel_icd.x86_64.json, version "1.0.0"

Instance Extensions:
====================
Instance Extensions count = 6
    VK_KHR_surface                      : extension revision 25
    VK_KHR_xcb_surface                  : extension revision  6
    VK_KHR_xlib_surface                 : extension revision  6
    VK_KHR_wayland_surface              : extension revision  5
    VK_KHR_mir_surface                  : extension revision  4
    VK_EXT_debug_report                 : extension revision  5
/build/vulkan-WFoCfr/vulkan-1.0.42.0+dfsg1/demos/vulkaninfo.c:1523: failed with VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
```

Here's the output from `lscpi`:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tobago PRO [Radeon R7 360 / R9 360 OEM] [1002:665f] (rev 81)
```

Specifically, my graphics card is a Radeon R7 360.

Is there something I need to do to activate the drivers? It feels like I'm missing something super obvious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this card is just not supported by RADV at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Check [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041394/problem-with-vulkan-on-ati-sapphire-7870-running-xubuntu-18-04/1042801#1042801). I had simmilar issue on my ATI Sapphire 7870 AND AMD Radeon 7870. (☞ﾟヮﾟ)☞

I believe that it could be an issue with `amdgpu` not loaded try to verify it using `lspci -k | grep "Kernel driver in use:"`.

Output should be `"Kernel driver in use: amdgpu"`.

If not Add NAND modify `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` with

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "AMD"
    Driver "amdgpu"
    Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

- `Option "TearFree" "true"` should fix problem with screen thearing.

Then modify `/etc/default/grub` as:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1"
```

finished with `sudo update-grub && sudo shutdown -r` to update grub and restart your device.

Then i would suggest `sudo usermod -a -G video $LOGNAME` [its recommended by AMD](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Install-LunarG-Vulkan-SDK.aspx) to fix this VK_ERROR.

Eventually i would suggest you to try hexchat on #radeon they should be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I don't think my card is supported by AMDGPU, since whenever I try to install it, X can't start.

Comment: i would try it anyway with those grub modifications `radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1` and if it doesn't work then switch `radeon.si_support=1 amdgpu.si_support=0`. nor ask on #radeon IRC channel. I believe that your GPU is supported. (don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` after each modification.)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the package libvulkan1 installed as well?  That's the loader library, and should have the correct ICD JSON files to point to the proper loader.

edit:
Also why don't you have API version 1.0.61?

Suggested fix for AMD:
https://askubuntu.com/a/970377/750714

related:
https://askubuntu.com/a/967910/750714

Comment: libvulkan1 appears to be pulled in by the packages above

Comment: API version is the one packaged with Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: /usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/radeon_icd.x86_64.json had "api_version": "1.0.3", fixed to 1.0.42, but no change

Comment: library_path is /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so, which is correct for my machine, since that file exists

Comment: I also don't have this file /usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/radeon_icd.i686.json
could that be  a problem?

Comment: That's only for using 32bit, which you likely won't need anyway unless you test drivers.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is to remove the absolute path from the lib*_path, but like I said I don't have an AMD install to verify 'how it should be' -- only have second hand info, sorry.I was mostly curious if the icd json was invalid like the known nvidia package bug for 17.10.