# VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER error with Vulkan on ATI Sapphire 7870 running (X)Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, radeon, amd-graphics, vulkan

I spent +- 22 hours trying to make it work, but I find more problems than solutions.

### PROBLEM

Steps to reproduce #1

- Fresh install of Ubuntu with Xubuntu DE.
- Follow official instructions - https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Install-LunarG-Vulkan-SDK.aspx

  https://pastebin.com/Lr1sa50v
- Row 15 - VULKAN_SDK=/home/kreyren/vulkan/VulkanSDK/1.0.37.0/x86_64 shoudn’t it be 1.1.73.0? (based on [AMD’s official instruction](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Install-LunarG-Vulkan-SDK.aspx))
- **VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER**

*SHORTED, MORE IN ORIGINAL DOC.*

### INFORMATION

- **GPU: ATI Sapphire 7870 AND AMD Radeon 7870AMD/ATI**

  - Manufacturer has two names for this GPU as far as i know.
  - GPU Supports Vulkan based on Test in Windows 10 running DotA 2 with “-vulkan” argument and wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_HD_7000_Series
- **OS: Tested on Debian 9, Xubuntu and Ubuntu.**

  - Right now I have fresh installation of Ubuntu with backup using Clonezilla and basic setup.
  - apt list --installed > /home/kreyren/Desktop/Installed_packages.txt
    https://pastebin.com/WrKWWbhg
  - Installed updates using `sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get upgrade -y && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y`
  - Distro has 20GB of root + 2GB swap on SSD and 100GB of /home on HDD
  - Verify that it's supported by AMD:

    - https://i.imgur.com/a/G9ETDK6
    - https://i.imgur.com/a/N0AWiLE

### TRIED SOLUTION

- add NAND modify `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` with

  ```
  Section "Device"
      Identifier "AMD"
      Driver "amdgpu"
      Option "TearFree" "true"
  EndSection
  ```
- Reboot > VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER

*SHORTED, MORE IN ORIGINAL DOC.*

### BACKSTORY

Original is available [on personal Google docs.](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IJvV1zWTJGyAdQONMTEFkoa5OYpsAqFPKz9NaYAPkuQ/edit#)

I made Facebook document where I tried to fix this issue with the help of other Linux users. Facebook document was removed after solution and the issue was posted on askubuntu! Hoping to reach more people with same issue.

Not enough reputation to post rest of the original and it seems pointless to spam with irelevant info, its here for those who are interested in this issue like Developers who could possibly fix this issue by default.

Comment: Self answering is encouraged here and I applaud your effort in solving your problem. Be that as it may, I encourage you to split this post into the **Question** (the problem that you had) in this box and the **Answer** (the solution you found) in the box below. AskUbuntu is a Q & A site and not a typical forum. You might find [the tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) informative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This solution may be outdated. It seems that only `mesa-vulkan-driver` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade` is needed to make vulkan API work. - Updated 10/07/2018*

I found the solution before i posted this answer this is repost recommended by @ElderGeek on forum. (•̀ᴗ•́)و

### Vulkan installation on AMD Radeon 7870 running Ubuntu 18.04 (possible other debian-based distros)

**NOTE:** I wasn't able to reproduce it on Debian 9.4.

**WARNING:** Grab a backup since systemd (or its alternatives) won't be able to boot with error something like: `ERR: Install
 firmware-amd-graphics package`.

**WARNING_EDIT:** It seems that package `firmware-amd-graphics` is now installd by default on Ubuntu 18.04. I noticed the change at 10/07/2018.

1. Run this command to update your system

   ```
   sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
   ```
2. Install Mesa Vulkan Drivers:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mesa-vulkan-drivers vulkan-utils
   ```
3. Modify kernel parameters in `/etc/default/grub` as:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 modprobe.blacklist=radeon"
   ```

   This should fix **VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER**.
4. To switch on amdgpu driver. (radeon's not working with this GPU.)
5. Run these commands:

   - `sudo update-grub` To update grub based on info in `/etc/default/grub` .
   - `sudo shutdown -r now` To restart your device.
   - `lspci -k | grep "Kernel driver in use:"` To verify that it's loaded correctly, output should be: `"Kernel driver in use: amdgpu"`.
6. Should show up in `vulkaninfo` without problems.

---

### In case it doesn't work

1. Add nor modify `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` AND `/etc/X11/20-amdgpu.conf` with the following content (reboot after this modifications):

   ```
   Section "Device"
       Identifier "AMD"
       Driver "amdgpu"
       Option "TearFree" "true"
   EndSection
   ```

   - `Option "TearFree" "true"` should fix problem with screen thearing.
2. Verify that amdgpu is loaded by loading GRUB and pressing <kbd>E</kbd>.
3. `sudo usermod -a -G video $LOGNAME`

   - Should fix "**VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED**".
   - Seems like magic, but [it's recommended by AMD](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Install-LunarG-Vulkan-SDK.aspx).
4. `sudo apt-get install hexchat > join #radeon` and ask for help.

Feel free to share your experience I'm willing to update this post. (☞ﾟヮﾟ)☞

Comment: I see step one in your question, so I'm not sure you need it in your answer. Did this problem begin when you upgraded your system from a previous version to 18.04? If so your question and this answer would be more useful if you would make that clear and which version you were upgrading from. I would assume 16.04 but I hate to assume anything. Cheers!

Comment: Actually i was upgrading from Windows 10 and this was first issue i had to deal with on Linux for this device. It seems to be problem on other versions too namely it seems that this GPU needs "amdgpu" drivers and fixes for VK_ERRORS to work as it should with vulkan possibly modifications to Xorg.conf.  (ｏ・_・)

+ to fix thearing

Comment: Editing details into your question would make it more valuable to the community by providing further clarity.  It's confusing (at least to me why you would run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y` on a fresh installation of 18.04 as there's currently no distribution upgrade path from 18.04 to anything else. The more valuable your posts are to the community the more upvotes you'll get leading to an increase in [priveleges](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges)

Comment: @ElderGeek You're right about that, sorry i've included it thinking to make sure that end-user has updated repositories and packages. Updating distro doen't make sence in this scenario. #Fixed

Aldo i woudn't post more info from document, most of it are irelevant to fix the issue i believe. ( •_•)